# Robot Framework - EDGE IE Mode Automation Possible?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

Currently Microsft provided solution via Python/Java to achieve this thing with addition two Options such as Edge_executable_Path,attach_to_edge_chrome. But how to achive the same with Robot Framework with IEDriver

Answer (score 0):

This is how you run Edge in Ie Mode with robot framework

```
*** Variables ***
${edgepath}    C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe
${AccessURL}    google.com
 
*** Keywords ***
Open Edge Browser In IE Mode   
    ${dic}=    Create Dictionary    ie.edgechromium=${True}   ie.edgepath=${edgepath}    ignoreProtectedModeSettings=${True}
    ${ieoptions}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Set To Dictionary    ${ieoptions}    se:ieOptions    ${dic}
    Open Browser    ${AccessURL}    ie    desired_capabilities=${ieoptions}
    SeleniumLibrary.Maximize Browser Window
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Settings ***

Library   SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

${IEDriver}  E:/webdriver/IEDriverServer.exe

*** Test Cases ***

Example Test

Open Browser  https://www.google.com/  ie  executable_path=${IEDriver}  options=ignore_zoom_level=True; attach_to_edge_chrome=True; edge_executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
Maximize Browser Window
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).